# Import xls data with dates

Tags: list-manipulation, excel, data-format

I have an excel table that have 2 columns, the first one are dates, and the second one are values. I want to plot the value vs the date. I need to: first clean all the non numbers strings like {"Junio",""}, then make the date to something that Mathematica would understand.

> {{"Unidad Indexada", ""}, {"Período Junio 2002 -", ""}, {"", ""}, {"",
>      "Valor"}, {"Fecha", "Pesos ($)"}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}, {"2 0 0 2", 
>     ""}, {"", ""}, {"Junio", ""}, {"", ""}, {{2002, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.}, {{2002, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0004}, {{2002, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0008}, {{2002, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0012}, {{2002, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0016}, {{2002, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.002}, {{2002, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0024}, {{2002, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0029}, {{2002, 6, 9, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0033}, {{2002, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0037}, {{2002, 6, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0041}, {{2002, 6, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0045}, {{2002, 6, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0049}, {{2002, 6, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0053}, {{2002, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0057}, {{2002, 6, 16, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0061}, {{2002, 6, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0065}, {{2002, 6, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0069}, {{2002, 6, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0074}, {{2002, 6, 20, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0078}, {{2002, 6, 21, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0082}, {{2002, 6, 22, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0086}, {{2002, 6, 23, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.009}, {{2002, 6, 24, 0, 0, 0.},
>      1.0094}, {{2002, 6, 25, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0098}, {{2002, 6, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0102}, {{2002, 6, 27, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0106}, {{2002, 6, 28, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0111}, {{2002, 6, 29, 0, 0, 0.}, 
>     1.0115}, {{2002, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0119}, {"", ""}, {"Julio", 
>     ""}, {"", ""}, {{2002, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0125},...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have your data stored in `data`, you can clean up the unwanted stuff using `Cases`:

```
newdata = Cases[data, {{__?NumericQ}, _}];
```

Then use `DateListPlot` to plot it:

```
DateListPlot[newdata]
```

Comment: How is that `__?NumericQ` is equal to `2002, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0.` ??

Comment: @Kafkarudo The `__` is `BlankSequence` and matches a sequence of one or more expressions, and `NumericQ` gives `True` if an expression is numeric (so numbers or symbols such as Pi).

Comment: In my opinion this pattern was too general and therefore too risky for large data.

Answer (score 1):

lets say your import data are

```
rawdata = {{"Unidad Indexada", ""}, {"Período Junio 2002 -", ""}, {"",    ""}, {"", "Valor"}, {"Fecha", "Pesos ($)"}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}, {"2 0 0 2", ""}, {"", ""}, {"Junio", ""}, {"", ""}, {{2002, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.}, {{2002, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0.},   1.0004}, {{2002, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0008}, {{2002, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0012}, {{2002, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0016}, {{2002, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.002}, {{2002, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0024}, {{2002, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0029}, {{2002, 6, 9, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0033}, {{2002, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0037}, {{2002, 6, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0041}, {{2002, 6, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0045}, {{2002, 6, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0049}, {{2002, 6, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0053}, {{2002, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0057}, {{2002, 6, 16, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0061}, {{2002, 6, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0065}, {{2002, 6, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0069}, {{2002, 6, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0074}, {{2002, 6, 20, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0078}, {{2002, 6, 21, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0082}, {{2002, 6, 22, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0086}, {{2002, 6, 23, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.009}, {{2002, 6, 24, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0094}, {{2002, 6, 25, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0098}, {{2002, 6, 26, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0102}, {{2002, 6, 27, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0106}, {{2002, 6, 28, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0111}, {{2002, 6, 29, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0115}, {{2002, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0119}, {"", ""}, {"Julio", ""}, {"", ""}, {{2002, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, 1.0125}};
```

And we just want to get all data of june in year 2002:

```
data = Select[rawdata, (#[[1, 1]](*year*)== 2002) && (#[[1, 2]](*month*)== 6) &]
```

you're lucky, the data have already `DateList` format

i.e.

```
DateString@data[[1, 1]]

(* out *)
"Sat 1 Jun 2002 00:00:00"
```

and you can do a plot immediately

```
DateListPlot@data
```

[image: datelist]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a Excel like this:

[image: excel]

The best way to import excel is through SemanticImport.(In version 10.0.0.0)

> mydata = SemanticImport["d:/1.xlsx"]

and you will get

[image: mathematica]

In my computer, Mathematica does not Process Date properly,So I did this:

> date = Normal@mydata[All, 1];
>
> date = StringCases[#, WordCharacter ..] & /@ date
>
> date = DateString /@ ToExpression[date]
>
> DateListPlot[Transpose[{date, Normal@mydata[All, 2]}]]

and finally

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
(* Import your data from the Excel file *)
originalData = Import["your file name here"];

(* This checks to see if the data in the first column has been broken into a 6 part list and if the data in the second column is numeric; the Select function will return items that match both criteria*)
cleanData = Select[originalData, Length[#[[1]]] == 6 && NumericQ[#[[2]]] &];

(* Plot the cleaned data *)
DateListPlot[cleanData]
```